# How to combine to arrays with diffrent fields

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{
    UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'): 
        [UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010'), 
        UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa'), 
        UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')], 

    UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'): 
        [UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')]
}

-------

[
    {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')}, 
    {u'count': 17, u'_id': UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')}, 
    {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa')}, 
    {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010')}
]
```

The first dictionary has account UUIDs as keys associated with arrays of machine group UUIDs that the account belongs to.
The array contains dictionaries that give the number of machines for each machine group UUID.

What I would like to have is the number of machines per account. How can I combine the two data sets to get that?

Answer (score 0):

So just to be make sure I understand: you've got two dictionaries.  The first maps from cloud_account to a list of machine_groups.  The second maps from machine_group to a list of machines.  You would like a map from cloud_account to number of total machines.  This snippet illustrates how to do that with a simple comprehension.

```
foo = {'A': ['foo', 'bar'], 'B': ['baz']}
bar = {'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'bar': ['d'], 'baz': ['e', 'f']}

baz = {k: sum(len(bar[k2]) for k2 in v) for k, v in foo.items()}
print(baz)
```

prints:

```
{'A': 4, 'B': 2}
```

Comment: It's something like that yes, but in the example you gave, what if in the second dictionnany the values of the keys ```foo``` and ```bar``` and ```baz``` where ```int```s ?

Comment: So `{'foo': 3, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2}`? As in those ints being the number of machines rather than a list of machine uuid's?  If that's the case then just remove the `len` call inside the comprehension: `{k: sum(bar[k2])....}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary I will refer to as `account_dict`, your array I will refer to as `group_array`.
To speed this up (especially if you have to do a lot of these), I first recommend creating a mapping of machine group UUIDs to machine counts:

```
group_count = {mg[u'_id']:mg[u'count'] for mg in group_array}
```

Now that you have this, you can create your mapping of accounts to total machine count in the following manner:

```
account_machine_count = {account: sum([group_count[group] for group in account_dict[account]])
                             for account in account_dict}
```

`sum([group_count[group] for group in account_dict[account]])` will go through all the groups in `account_dict` for each account, look up their machine count in the `group_count` dict we created, and add them all together.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote long to clarify what I got from your descriptions (Hope this help you):

```
from uuid import UUID

groups = {UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'):
          [UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010'),
           UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa'),
           UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')],
          UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'): [UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')]}

group_machines = [{u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a')},
                  {u'count': 17, u'_id': UUID(
                      'c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520')},
                  {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID(
                      'a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa')},
                  {u'count': 1, u'_id': UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010')}]

result_detail = {}
result_sum = {}

for group_id, machines_id in groups.items():
    for machine_id in machines_id:
        machine_count = tuple(
            filter(lambda m_details: m_details['_id'] == machine_id, group_machines))
        if machine_count:
            if group_id not in result_detail:
                result_sum[group_id] = machine_count[0][u'count']
                result_detail[group_id] = [
                    {machine_id: machine_count[0][u'count']}]
            else:
                result_sum[group_id] = result_sum[group_id] + \
                    machine_count[0][u'count']
                result_detail[group_id].append(
                    {machine_id: machine_count[0][u'count']})

print(result_detail)
#{UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'): [{UUID('d0576830-df96-4411-ac33-4bac597f2010'): 1}, {UUID('a650e642-ee41-4ab7-8ad1-797c7bdcd2aa'): 1}, {UUID('c0a36d2e-f7dd-4d62-abe8-c26249e52520'): 17}], UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'): [{UUID('31140d2e-15a1-4203-bdbb-55c14cd6b83a'): 1}]}
print(result_sum)
#{UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'): 19, UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'): 1}
```

**Shorter:**

```
from functools import reduce
result = {group_id: reduce(lambda s, m_detail: s + m_detail[u'count'],
                           filter(lambda m_detail: m_detail[u'_id'] in machines_id,
                                  group_machines),
                           0)
          for group_id, machines_id in groups.items()}

print(result)
#{UUID('a639efb6-d4e0-4929-b309-8171bf61b508'): 19, UUID('fd4bbf86-9803-4724-9576-d83355bdcff2'): 1}
```